# Loading data from MongoDB in IMap in Hazelcast when using Client-Server Topology

Tags: java, mongodb, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

In an embedded topology I implement a MapStore and MapLoaderLifecycleSupport to load data from MongoDB when the IMap is initialized. How do I do the same when using JAVA clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont do anything on clients except invoking IMap APIs. MapStore/Loader implementation sits on servers and that is also where it is used. For example - when you do a `hazelcast_map.get(some_key)`, this operation goes to one of the servers in the cluster. If the key `some_key` is present in the cache of the server then it will be returned to the application, otherwise the server will invoke `map_loader.load(some_key)` in your MapLoader implementation, get the value returned by the `load`, store in cache and return to the client.

Comment: When you say that MapStore/Loader sits on server Do you mean it has to be implemented in the Member.java code. Like earlier it was being implemented through the MongoMapStore class in the MongoDB integration example how do I combine it with the client basic example as given in the github example codes. I need to do two configuration here one for the client and another for configMapStore

Comment: MongoMapStore is the implementation of MapStore but it needs to configured on server side. The servers need to know which MapStore implementation they need to use if its enabled. This can be configured either in `hazelcast.xml` or through Java code where you initialise and create a Map (MemberProgrammatic in this example).

Comment: I do  the map.loadAll in member.java and then use that map to access values in client.java

Comment: i figured out how to connect a client and a member and load the data from MongoDB. But suppose I have a web app running in a tomcat container then I need to put the client code in the web app and it will run in the tomcat container along with the code for the web app. How do I configure the client side code so that it connects to the member instance running on the server